# Updating module using _update_n not appearing on update.php or in /modules/update

Tags: 7, updating

I had to change the schema of a module I created. I added a function like this:

```
function cloudinary_update_7200() {    

  $spec = array(
    'keywords' => array('type' => 'longtext', 'not null' => FALSE),
    'primaryImage' => array('type' => 'tinyint', 'default' => 1, 'not null' => FALSE)
  );    

  $cloudinary_field_table = 'field_data_field_cloudinary';
  $revision_table_name = 'field_revision_field_cloudinary';    

  $keywords = 'field_cloudinary_keywords';
  db_add_field($cloudinary_field_table, $keywords, $spec);
  db_add_field($revision_table_name, $keywords, $spec);    

  $primaryImage = 'field_cloudinary_primaryImage';
  db_add_field($cloudinary_field_table, $primaryImage, $spec);
  db_add_field($revision_table_name, $primaryImage, $spec);    

  //UPDATE FIELDS
  $description_spec = array(
    'description' => array('type' => 'longtext', 'not null' => FALSE)
  );
  db_change_field($cloudinary_field_table, "field_cloudinary_alt", "field_cloudinary_description", $description_spec);    

}
```

So how do I get it to run? I've gone to /update.php but nothing. I tried /admin/modules/update and the module is not listed.

Yes, I have cleared my cash many many times. And yes, I've cleared it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename cloudinary_update_7200 to cloudinary_update_7100 in case if you are using 7.1 version (refer to [hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7)) and try once again.

If it doesn't work perform SQL query to figure out the number of the latest performed update  of the module:

`SELECT schema_version FROM system WHERE type = 'module' AND name = 'cloudinary';`

If it is 0 - 7100 should work, if it is for instance 7101 - try cloudinary_update_7102.

Comment: That is a great tip re the select statement. thanks Rostislav!